# More efficient way to format an array without adding a '-' with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a program that filters through a list of words based on keywords from an array that I created. Currently I have the array setup where if there is a keyword such as "java script" i also need to add "java-script" to ensure when the user inputs the list of words it filters it out even if it is in a different format. Is there a more efficient way to do this so I don't have to duplicate every keyword within the array by adding a dash in between spaces?

any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```js
// Function for filter button
$('.pbf-link-container[contenteditable]').html('<div><br/></div>');
$('#pbf-filter').click(function() {
  var $pbfOutput = $('.pbf-link-container[contenteditable]').html();
  // Array of words for filter
  var pbfFilterWords = ['baby bullet', 'baby-bullet', 'java script', 'java-script', 'key word', 'key-word', 'keyword'];
  // Output to new DIV and remove specified keywords from pbfFilterWords
  $('.pbf-link-output').html($pbfOutput);
  // To make pbfFilterWords not case sensitive
  $.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function(elem) {
      return $(elem).html().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
  });
  // Function to output the filtered words
  $.each(pbfFilterWords, function(i, val) {
    $('.pbf-link-output > div:contains("' + val + '")').remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.pbf-header {
  text-align: center;
}

.pbf-link-container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: visible;
}

.pbf-button-control {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2%;
}

.pbf-filter-header {
  text-align: center;
}

.pbf-link-output {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: visible;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  margin: 3%;
}

.pbf-footer {
  display: block;
  padding: 2%;
  background-color: #111;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="pbf-container">
    <div class="pbf-header">
      <h1> VERO Filter Program </h1>
      <h3> Input Links Here </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="pbf-link-container" contenteditable="true">
    </div>
    <div class="pbf-button-control">
      <button id="pbf-filter"> Filter </button>
    </div>
    <div class="pbf-filter-header">
      <h3> Filtered Links </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="pbf-link-output">
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="\VERO Filter\pbf.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: I would use regex like `java.*script`

Comment: you can first loop through the keywords, duplicating and replacing the space with a dash.

Comment: @MaxZoom: would that RX hit "java is not script"? if so, surely that's incorrect...

Comment: I am not sure if it is correct or not, it depeneds on the user intentions - check [this](https://regex101.com/r/ZXfhVR/2) demo.

Answer (score 1):

That is a nice idea to think of...

I tryed your snippet using `hello hell-o jello`
What would be the recognition algorythm on words you would choose to target?

--

This issue, I think, is already addressed by some big sites with big server capabilities.
The search engines... There is many teams on that.
So nice idea!

But on the front-side where **JS** executes... The user side, on his medium range mobile consumer «can drop» device....

The simple idea of having to cycle throught a 10 kilometer long "buzz words" `array` to find matches or *"close to"* matches...
**Should not be a think of.**

---

*--- Yes. That definitely is an opinion. ---*
But it saves the math time when seen like this.

I suggest you think of an "auto-complete" function or plugin ([maybe this one? Theres is a couple](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)) with your own known buzz words.

And maybe a <kbd>Suggest a new?</kbd> button on no relevant match.

This is programmatically the shortest path, from what I know.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I am still working on this issue a few hours a day trying to figure out the most efficient method. I am trying to wrap my head around reg expressions but most likely it's looking like its going to be a long list inside an array with all possible combinations of the word. I will keep everyone updated once I figure this out.